# Apache camel Quartz start immediatly after application startup and then every hour

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, spring-camel

How can i configure my camel quartz to be triggered just after application startup and then every hour.
is there a property or an option that i can use in order to achieve my need.

Bellow is my route definition

```
@Component
public class LoadUserQuartzRoute extends BaseRoute {

    public LoadUserQuartzRoute() {
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        from(triggerQuartz())
                .routeId("loadUsers")

                .bean(UserService.class, "load")

                .to("destination");
    }

    public String triggerQuartz() {
        return quartz("groupScheduler/loadUsers")
                .triggerStartDelay(0)
                .cron("0 0 * ? * * *")
                .getUri();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciate !!

Answer (score 0):

The Quartz schedule runs at specific times of day.

Instead you could use the Timer component with settings like delay=0 fixedRate=true period=3600000

See https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/timer-component.html

Comment: hi @bgossit, thanks for your reply. 
Actually this approch does not exactly fit my need, cause i have to run my quartz at a specific period of the day, i mean a fixed time like every Monday at 1AM when the change can happen but before that period i need to fill my cache once the application has startedup. I know in old version of camel quartz (quartz2) it was the option fireNow to do that but in the new version i can't find it !!!

Comment: You could still use a Timer route for the initial job - delay=0 and repeatCount=1.

The Camel 3 upgrade discusses fireNow being removed and instead being able to set the start time in the past https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_13.html